# What is the correct Regex Pattern to find a specific set of String in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I obtained a row of String from an ArrayList which appears something like,

`[(Pixel Quality) (Year of Release) (Movie Title).ext....]` for movies or
`[songname-artistname.ext]` these all appear in a row.

In context it would be
`[(HD,720p) (1999) Tarzan.mpg, (SD,480p) (2001) Akira.mov,...... Hello-Adele.wav]`

This is the method I used,

```
    public void FindPatterns () {

        String patternFilms = ("[REGEX PATTERN]");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternFilms);

        for (String name : names) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

            while(matcher.find()){

                System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
            }
        }
    }
```

I left "REGEX PATTERN" there as a placeholder because I am not sure how to use one for a specific set of String. I am trying to identify the String by the extensions (.mpg,.flv...etc) first. Later on I will try doing it with the Year of Release and Pixel Quality.

And with that I am hoping I can get like a specific set of String like `(HD,720p) (1999) Tarzan.mpg` by match the file extension **".mpg"**

Comment: [This might help you](https://regex101.com/r/yP4bY4/1)

Comment: It helps a bit, but for someone who is unfamiliar with regex patterns it's quite hard to look through it and properly grasp what's going on.

Comment: That may be but this is true for anything that is unfamiliar to someone. In JavaScript there exists a package for verbal regular expressions that also has a Java implementation (https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JavaVerbalExpressions) that may help you.

Comment: Is it at all possible to have someone at least give me 1 example of how it can be implemented? Perhaps in my context.